# WPF 3D Display Very Slowly

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, 3d

I have a problem looking forward to your suggestions about WPF 3D performance.
It runs quite well with a small width and length, but with a width and length of about 949x825
When measured by stopwatch, all of the implementation in c# code only takes about 0.6 seconds, but it takes about 6 seconds for it to display 3D images in screen and when using the mouse to zoom or rotate the 3D image it is very slow. Is there any way to increase performance?

Code in C#:

```
        // **Test with width = 949 and length = 825. It's very slow**
        // Make a mesh to hold the surface.
        MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
        Int32Collection triangleIndices = new Int32Collection();
        Point3DCollection positions = new Point3DCollection();

        //defining point and triangles
        int ind1 = 0;
        int ind2 = 0;

        for (var z = 0; z < length; z++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                var point = new Point3D(x, map[z, x] * ImageConstants.YScale, z);
                positions.Add(point);

                if (z < length - 1 &&
                    x < width - 1)
                {
                    ind1 = x + z * width;
                    ind2 = ind1 + width;

                    //first triangle
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind1);
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind2);
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind2 + 1);

                    //second triangle
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind1);
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind2 + 1);
                    triangleIndices.Add(ind1 + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        mesh.Positions = positions;
        mesh.TriangleIndices = triangleIndices;
```

In Xaml:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Background="Black" MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel" MouseDown="OnMouseDown">
        <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport3D">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="MainPerspectiveCamera" FieldOfView="35" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup x:Name="MainModel3DGroup">
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you rotate/zoom. Do you change the mesh or the camera/mesh transform? How large is the mesh?

Comment: I rotate/zoom with camera, about large mesh, example width=949 and length = 825 as same as above code I think it equal width*length*2 = 1,565,850 triangles

Comment: When scrolling the mouse I change with ScaleTransform3D to zoom, and with rotate I change Camera Position

Comment: I have some experience using wpf-3D, and would expect better performance than 1/6 fps, even if the mesh is slightly on the large side. But I do not know why it is slow, it does not look like you are doing anything odd. Have you checked that GPU acceleration is used? If the GPU is very old it might fall back to software rendering.

Comment: I think the problem is that it has too many triangles, but I don't know how to reduce it. Anyway Thank you very much @JonasH

Comment: when you say "I rotate/zoom with camera, about large mesh, example width=949 and length = 825 as same as above code I think it equal width*length*2 = 1,565,850 triangles"
Does this means that your mesh is a kind of a grid on the screen depending on its resolution???
a "normal" mesh is just a set of faces (quasi) independant of the resolution (unless you're using ray tracing)